# Adding UIPickerView to a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, uipickerview

I want to add a UIPickerView to a UITableViewCell. Right now I am just getting a black window. Can someone also explain me the concept of subclassing UI objects to a cell ie:when do we make our cell as the delegate and the datasource delegate? Thanks

EDIT: Here is the code of what i am doing right now

```
 case 1:  {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"groups"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"groups"];
        }
            /*NSString *myGroupDetail = [_groupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"the group detail label is %@",myGroupDetail);
            cell.textLabel.text = myGroupDetail;
            */
        [cell addSubview:_groupPicker];

        break;

    }
```

The groups is the section in which I want the picker view, I am getting that data from an array.
[image: Here is what i want to implement]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you would have to allocate and initialize a pickerview in your cellForRow method of the tableviewdelegate. ill sketch it for you =) how to initialize a cell itself should not be hard to find out if you google a bit ;-)

```
...(tableView *)... cellForRowAtIndexPath... {

if(indexPath.row == pickerRow){
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
    cell = ... // alloc and initialize a cell
    cell addSubview:pickerView];
    }
else{ // your other cells }   

return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE:** im currently having trouble with git, so i uploaded a sample project to my private server: [UITablePicker example](http://www.ethz.sflueckiger.ch/UITablePicker.zip)

github: https://github.com/sebamisc/UItableViewWithPicker

yu can modify and use the code however you want =)

sebastian

Comment: i have updated my code i am using the same thing .. i have my delegate and datasource hooked up to the viewcontroller using storyboard. Still getting a black screen ... Thanks for the reply

Comment: I have updated the question, should i post my delegate methods also ?

Comment: i have created a little sample project and attached it to my answer =) have fun with it.

Comment: check out the sample project i linked to in my answer =) this should answer all of your questions. dont forget the pickerviewdelegate etc =) play around with it a bit (you can use the code of course)

Comment: Thanks a lot :D .. really helpful - one question - We are making the cell as the delegate for the picker view ? sorry for the noob question i am still a beginner ..

Comment: i made the viewcontroller itself the delegate for the pickerview. 
those are the methods completely on the bottom where i return the variables from the array. i actually copied the code for the pickerviewdelegate methods from here: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uipickerview-creating-simple-picker.html (was a bit lazy). but you can see very simple how to initialize it like that.

you have to pay attention - if your tableview gets more than 1 row with my code all of them will hold a picker, so you wil have to make cases (if) in the cellforrowatindexpath method =) (indexPath.row)

Comment: I have a slightly differing requirement wherein I want the picker (or anything like that) to also have a button to discard. Also, my picker doesn't have to be tied to the cell. I used the code suggested but am unable to pass values from picker back to the table view controller. Any idea?

Comment: you need to set [pickerView setDelegate:yourTableViewController];

Answer (score 0):

Well, I never did exactly that.

Does it have to be in a cell or could you use the table's header or footer view for that? (I would not suggest a section header/footer view.)

Assuming it is within a UITableViewCell. 
Yes, I personally would subclass UITableViewCell. Did that a lot. In that case you cell object could be the data source delegate of the picker. For doing so your subclass of UITableViewCell (let's assume you name it MyTableViewCell) needs to fulfil the related protocol. You add that UIPickerView programmatically within the init Method (initWithStyle) of MyTableViewCell. For the layout within the table cell, you should overwrite the method layoutSubviews. If your app can be rotated to landscape and portrait orientations and/or if your app is designed to run on iPad as well, then this method should dynamically consider the table's bounds. (Screen or windwo bounds are often used hiere but that is not save when the table is displayed within a split master view or a popup view on iPads.)

Strictly spoken your MyTableViewCell should not be the data source delegate, simply because it is a view element and view objects are not supposed to manage any business logic within an MVC design pattern. Smarter would be the implementation of some dedicated view controller for your table view cell hat fulfills the protocol and is assigned as the delegate. However, both would work. In the event that it is the only picker view within your sell, then you could easily use your UITableViewController subclass even without tagging the UIPickerView.

An alternative to subclassing a UITableViewCell is to create the UIPickerView within the cellForRowAtIndexPath method of your tableViewController. That is fine for singe-orientation apps. However, you may setup it in a way that it re-arranges its the UIPickerView automatically.

In any case you should overwrite the heightForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableViewController when your table views do not have the same hight any more. If all of them still have the same height, then you can simply set the rowHeight property of your UITableView.

Comment: I have updated my question.. what do you suggest i do ? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The example that Sebastian has linked looks ok for me. It is designed for a table with one cell only. Just consider that your table is a bit more complex. That means that the content of cellForRowAtIndexPath in the example goes into your "case 1" block. And your heightForRowAtIndexPath should return 180.0f only for section 1 and 30.0f (or whatever is appropriate) in all other cases. The hole thing should work fine when there is only one picker in the table view. If you add a second picker later then you need to amend the solution.

Comment: Yea it great , the example given. Everything works great. Now the problem i have is how to decrease the size of the picker ie: the height of the picker. i have googled and seen that Apple have it fixed and there is no direct method of changing it.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately that is one of the disadvantages of the picker view. Any attempt to shrink it will only result in parts of it being cut of - if any visible change at all.