# Adding UIDatePicker to cell content view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uidatepicker, nstableviewcell

I'm attempting to put an instance of UIDatePicker in the accessory view of a UITableView cell, and have been following this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690013/adding-uipickerview-to-a-uitableviewcell) as a template. However, it looks as if the picker is being placed above the cell entirely:

[image]

Below is the code I'm using to try to add a Date Picker to the accessory view of a UITableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellNewRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RowCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.922 green:0.937 blue:0.949 alpha:1];

    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case EmployeeOvertimeRow:
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Test", @"One");
            _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
            _datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
            //OLD: cell.accessoryView     = _datePicker;
            //POST EDIT
            [cell.contentView addSubview:_datePicker];

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Does anyone have any guidance on what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `accessoryView` of a `UITableViewCell` is surely not what you think : it's the little view at the right of the cell, typically, it's an arrow, and it's pretty small, not made to be the width of the screen at all. You should try adding your view to the `contentView`. You will need to set a bigger height for your cell in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, too.

Comment: Thank you Emilie, the reason I was confused about the accessory view was that elsewhere in the code (that I inherited), a UISwitch was added to the accessory view of the cell, so I was trying to replicate that with a UIDataPicker. 

I changed the offending line to be:             [cell.contentView  addSubview:_datePicker];

However, at the moment, I don't have a heightForRowAtIndexPath method implemented, just a heightForHeaderInSection method, so I'll need to change that..